# Are questions about identity theft on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I'm wondering if questions about identity theft are on topic for this site. Specifically, I'm referring to questions about techniques to guard against it, how to recognize when it happens, what to do if it happens to you, etc. I know that these are mostly legal issues, but the playground of identity theft is personal finance, and it is in that sphere that these issues are applied.

Comment: I think so.  Depending on how the question is worded, I think financial security/ID theft protection and consciousness is very relevant.

Comment: There is a [related question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2343/10997) discussing the "fraud", "scams", and "identity-theft" tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is on-topic. We even have a tag for it: [identity-theft](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity-theft)

On our [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), identity theft questions fall under the category of "Consumer issues or consumer protections."